# Suggested synonym/retag: rename "stargate-movie"  to "stargate"

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retagging

We have 2 questions tagged [stargate-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate-movie). Both are ALSO tagged [stargate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate).

It seems that there's very little point to have a specific tag for a movie - of those 2 questions, only 1 was actually about a movie (the second one was based on the whole franchise, not movie-specific), and having that movie tag fully separate makes no sense IMHO - it is correct theoretically but in practice serves no useful purpose and is merely adding noise.

I proposed to change [stargate-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate-movie) to be a synonym of [stargate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate)

If you agree, and have >=5 upvotes in [stargate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate), please feel free to up-vote the synonym suggestion here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/stargate/synonyms

If approved, I will take care of minor re-tagging if it will be necessary.

Comment: Why not remove the tag [tag:stargate-movie] altogether?

Comment: @Gilles - So any future questions that people accidentally tag this way to always be in stargate tag. I don't think that stargat-movie should be banned/restricted.

Answer (score 2):

The Stargate-movie is quite different in general than Stargate the series. I'm not opposed to leaving this one alone.

Comment: There's already series tag. "stargate" is NOT the TV series tag (that's stargate-sg1 and stargate-universe and presumably stargate-atlantis though I don't recall any Atlantis Qs)

Comment: @DVK: But if you look at the questions with the stargate tag, they almost all refer to the TV series.

Comment: Is there any need to have the TV-series stargate tag?  If the question covers all three shows, couldn't it have all three tags?  If someone wants to follow all of them, they can use stargate-*.  So we could get rid of [tag:stargate] and just have the movie and individual shows?

Comment: @TonyMeyer: If that's going to be the will of the community, then let's do the same thing for Star Trek as well. Otherwise, I say let's just leave it how it is.

Comment: There are more star-trek tags than you can have tags on a question.  I'm curious how many [tag:star-trek] questions are about ST in general rather than specifically one/two shows - maybe it too is not useful.  Note that I was asking if there was a need, not suggesting that there isn't.  I haven't followed the SG questions enough to know the answer.